# not getting data from openSky network

Tags: reactjs, api

How do I get the information (data) from the Open-Sky Network? Its not rendering, I don't how to go about it.
This is my code. I'm trying to get the information

```
const = [flights, setFlights] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all')
                .then((res) => {
                    return res.json();
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                });
    
    }, [])
```

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?